# How do I delete/remove an app from a Firebase project?

Tags: firebase

Where is the delete/remove button???

Attached is a screenshot of what I want to do.

[image: firebase app delete]

Comment: From console.firebase.google.com go to project OverView next find setting (Cog) click on  Project settings then scroll down click on the button delete this app pop up delete app permanently.  Then click on the Delete project its pop a window copy the bold project name and paste into Project ID, enables Delete Project button and click on it......... Hurry Now its deleted from your firebase account.

Answer (score 85):

UPDATE: There is now an option to delete an app within your project. Go to your Firebase console, click app's setting gear, click manage. Click on the **Advance Option**'s arrow, you'll see **DELETE THIS APP**.

[image]
[image]

--Old Answer--

There is no option to delete app, just the project. When you go to the setting icon of your app, click on Manage then you'll see the "Delete Project" below.

Comment: @user142020a you should go to the support link on the Firebase console and go to "request a feature".

Comment: May I know can I delete a project in firebase?

Comment: Answer:
On Project Settings page, you scroll down and see a section of "Your apps".
Here you can click on the app you want to delete.
you will see a "Remove this app" button based on permissions you have on the project.
Use this button to permanently delete the app.

ref: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7047853?hl=en