# How to completely disconnect an Android app from Firebase (in Android studio)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console

I want to completely disconnect my app from Firebase. This question has been asked several times (e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486516/how-do-i-delete-remove-an-app-from-a-firebase-project/37487344)). Most of the answers focus on disconnecting an app from Firebase **within the Firebase console** and not **within Android studio**.

After disconnecting my app from the Firebase console. Everytime I try to reconnect the app to another Firebase project, an error balloon pops up stating that the app is already part of a Firebase project. I know this behaviour occurs because some files from the old Firebase project are still present. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: I don't think it occurs because of the files from the old project. The occurs because the app is still connected to the Firebase Console.

Comment: Most likely you still have a dependency on a Firebase module. Check your `build.gradle` files and/or add them to your question if you'd like us to check.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes, that's not the issue. My first step was to remove the app from the Firebase console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should undo all the steps that you are instructed to perform in the [manual integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).  So, remove all Firebase dependencies from build.gradle, remove the Google Services plugin from the bottom of build.gradle, and remove the google-services.json file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I followed this step but the issue is still there. Are there any auto-generated files I need to delete too?

Answer (score 16):

Try these steps to remove Fire-base from Android Studio project.

> Delete `google-services.json` file from the Project (Find the file by Project view)
>
> Remove dependencies from Project-level `build.gradle` (/build.gradle)

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Remove this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
  }
}
```

> Remove all the Fire-base related dependencies from the project App-level `build.gradle` (//build.gradle) file

```
dependencies {
   // Remove this line
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}
```

> Remove the line below from the bottom of the App-level `build.gradle` (//build.gradle) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 7):

Try this, On the project level, delete the google-services.json file 
[image]

and then sync the project 
[image]

Comment: Although I had this problem about 4 months ago, I never eventually found a solution. I remember doing this though. Worthy solution but this did not solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down the Firebase project created with the package name of the connected application; although it doesn't delete at the same time and is scheduled for later. Don't link your android app with any other firebase app till the previous connected app has been deleted completely.

Comment: I have other apps connected to the Firebase project. Deletion is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

On the main menu, select app ,select ,google-services.json' and then right click then delete

Answer (score -1):

Do the following (If you want to Switch Firebase Data Sources):
In Android Studio, Go to Tools>Firebase, Choose any of the options such as Real time-database
Click Connect to Firebase.
You will get a warning that the App is already connected to Firebase. 
Click okay. 
Android Studio will open a Firebase console on a browser. 
Choose the Firebase App you want to you want to connect to. 
Done.

Comment: When it tells me the app is already connected to Firebase, the options provided are "sync" and "cancel". Sync only updates the information locally. Is your answer correct or was there a step I missed?