# How can I change the google firebase of my already linked android app, to another google firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I had a google account say xyz@gmail.com which is **not recoverable** now. I was using that account's Google Firebase as the backend for my Android project say ABC App. What are the steps that need to be taken so that I can change the Google Firebase of ABC app to another Gmail account say qrs@gmail.com?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solved. I disconnected the firebase from the app
shown here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549554/how-to-completely-disconnect-an-android-app-from-firebase-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Go to that project in `Firebase` in `xyz@gmail.com` in **Users & Permission** section add `qrs@gmail.com` user there as owner.You get email of invitation at `qrs@gmail.com` . Accept invitation.  Now you can get all database configurations in `qrs@gmail.com` account.

No need to change any thing just alot `qrs@gmail.com` that database and you can get all stuff their.

[image]

Comment: The problem is i cant access the firebase of xyz@gmail.com as i have forgot the password to it.

Comment: Any other member added to that account?

Comment: unfortunately no