# I've mistakenly connected my iOS App(flutter) to the wrong firebase project, can I change firebase projects?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

Is there away to change my iOS App to a different firebase project. I've connected the wrong project!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide GoogleService-Info.plist file for the firebase project you want to connect your app to

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can [delete the app from the first project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486516/how-do-i-delete-remove-an-app-from-a-firebase-project) and add it to the second.  You will need to get a new configuration file from the new project and add it to your app.